# Rails 5, Postgres, ActiveRecord - how to include function value as model field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-trgm

I am using the Trigram module (pg_trgm) for Postgres in a Rails 5 application for text search.  I have been able to successfully find satisfactory results using the following call to find a *limit* number of records whose names are similar to the *query*:

```
  def self.glance(query, limit = 10)
    find_by_sql(['select *, name <-> ? as confidence from studies order by confidence limit ?', query, limit])
  end
```

I would now like to extend the results to include the value of the **similarity** function for each record and the target **query** for display.

I am taken to believe I should setup a scope (or class method) where I can make the parameterized call to the distance operator (name <-> ?) and then have the value returned as if it was an attribute in the database model.

May I have a recommendation on best practice for doing this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `study` model, I thought you can use a scope and LIKE implemented following:

```
scope :glance, ->(query, limit = 10) { where('name LIKE %?%', query).order(:confidence).limit(limit) }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried this but got a syntax error (am sure I messed this up though).  But, I am actually trying to use the pg_trgm function '<->' not LIKE.  I ended up using ILIKE but I was trying to get the search extension for trigrams to work.  Here's the syntax error:  PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "studies" WHERE (name LIKE %'drone'%) ...

Comment: The raw SQL should be `SELECT 1 AS one FROM "studies" WHERE (name LIKE %drone%)`... not included `'`. So, you could change something like  `..where('name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%")...`

Comment: I appreciate all of the referencing to using LIKE but I'm using trigram ([pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html)) and the <-> distance operator and it's that which I'm trying to understand.